# NodeJs / Express: avoid sequential processing of many files

Tags: node.js, express, multiprocessing

I have an Express webhook that gets rarely called:

```
app.use('/convert', async (req, res) => {
  const files = await getFiles();
  for(let file of files) {
    await download(file);
    await convert(file);
    await upload(file)
  }
  res.send('finished');
```

}

Each iteration of the loop takes a few minutes, there may be hundreds of files to process. How can I avoid sequential processing here?

Thanks much

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.map` along with `Promise.all` to process everything concurrently. Doing everything concurrently could be very resource heavy, so you may want to process in batches, or some kind of queue based processing, but that depends on your requirements.

Comment: I had thought that I would need to spawn more node processes to do the work in parallel? Or is that queue / batch processing?

Comment: Assuming `download`, `convert`, and `upload` are truly asynchronous you should not need additional node processes. If any of the code you're running blocks (e.g. is synchronous and takes a long time to run), then you may want to consider forking node.

Comment: thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to process everything concurrently. The `Promise` specification has some methods for working with multiple promises simultaneously, for this we'll want to use `Promise.all`.

```
app.use('/convert', async (req, res) => {
    const files = await getFiles();
    const promises = files.map(async (file) => {
        await download(file);
        await convert(file);
        await upload(file)
    });
    await Promise.all(promises);
    res.send('finished');
}
```

Although doing everything at once is relatively simple, it can be very resource heavy. It's unclear how `download`, `convert`, and `upload` work internally but it's very possible that you could hit the limit of the machine resources. To avoid things like hitting the open file limit, or running out of memory there should be a limit to the number of items being processed concurrently.

One way is to process items in batches. To process in batches you could simply split the array of `files` into chunks and combine the solution above with your iterative solution.

```
app.use('/convert', async (req, res) => {
    const files = await getFiles();

    const chunkSize = 5;
    const chunks = [];
    while (files.length) {
        chunks.push(files.splice(0, chunkSize));
    }

    for (const chunk of chunks) {
        const promises = chunk.map(async (file) => {
            await download(file);
            await convert(file);
            await upload(file)
        });
        await Promise.all(promises);
    }
    res.send('finished');
});
```

The implementation above will wait for `chunkSize` items to finish processing before queuing up another `chunkSize` items for processing. Because it waits for all items to finish it's possible that some of the items process very quickly, but others take much longer. In this case you end up under utilizing your resources. Ideally you would always be processing `chunkSize` items at a time. To do this you can queue up `chunkSize` "threads" for processing, each "thread" will process one item at a time until there is nothing left to process.

```
async function process(file) {
    await download(file);
    await convert(file);
    await upload(file);
}

async function thread(files) {
    while (files.length) {
        await process(files.pop());
    }
}

app.use('/convert', async (req, res) => {
    const files = await getFiles();

    let maxConcurrency = 5;

    const threads = [];
    while (--maxConcurrency) {
        threads.push(thread(files));
    }
    await Promise.all(threads);

    res.send('finished');
});
```

Comment: thanks for this great answer. not only does it work well, but it's educational too.