# Nodejs: limited parallel execution hangs near end of processing

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I am processing some files according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63475255/nodejs-express-avoid-sequential-processing-of-many-files/63476267#63476267) question. My code looks like:

```
const procFile = async (url) => {
  await download(url);
  await convert(url);
  await upload(url);
};

const thread = async (urls) => {
  while (urls.length) {
    await procFile(urls.pop());
  }
};

const start = async (urls) => {
  const threads = [];
  const maxConcurrency = 4;

  for (let _ of new Array(maxConcurrency)) {
    threads.push(thread(urls));
  }

  await Promise.all(threads);
}
```

Whenever I set `maxConcurrency` to a vlue greater than 1, the program will eventually hang and the greater the value of `maxConcurrency` the sooner it hangs. The program gets stuck in an infinite loop inside the `emitHook` method of the NodeJs core module `async_hooks`.

Using `Node 14`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're not catching any errors in the code above. Most likely it's not hanging but some external service is causing an error and js simply stops processing because you're not handling errors (note that from node's perspective catching the error and doing nothing is a valid way to not break program flow - but you must catch it even with an empty block: `catch (err) {/* nothing */}`). Ideally you should log the error to see what went wrong

Comment: in my actual code I do catch the errors. but no errors get thrown. it just gets caught in the `emitHook` function...

Comment: It seems you're trying to modify the exact same `urls` collection in all parallel `thread` calls.

Comment: I am. Is that bad? I thought the idea was for `urls` to function as a queue from which all the "threads" could pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple concurrency using plain JS ([Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-browser-nllrv?file=/src/index.js)):

```
function concurrency(arr, map, limit){
    let pendingCount= 0;
    const results= [];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        function pump(){
            while (arr && arr.length && pendingCount < limit) {
                pendingCount++;
                map(arr.shift()).then(result=>{
                    pendingCount--;
                    results.push(result);
                    pump();
                }, err=> {
                    arr= null;
                    reject(err)
                });
            }

            if(!pendingCount){
                return resolve(results);
            }
        }

        pump();
    })
}

concurrency([
    'url1',
    'url2',
    'url3',
    'url4',
    'url5',
    'url6',
], async(url)=>{
    await download(url);
    await convert(url);
    return upload(url);
}, 2).then(results=> console.log(`Results: `, results));
```

Or you can try to use any library with concurrency limit functionality, e.g [Bluebird.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird), [p-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-limit), [CPromise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-promise2)
([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-butterfly-rud8l?file=/index.html))

```
const CPromise= require('c-promise2');

async function download(url){
    console.log(`download ${url}`);
    return CPromise.delay(1000)
}
async function convert(url){
    console.log(`convert ${url}`)
}
async function upload(url){
    console.log(`upload ${url}`)
}

(async()=>{
    await CPromise.all([
        'url1',
        'url2',
        'url3',
        'url4',
        'url5',
        'url6',
    ], {
        mapper: async (url) => {
            await download(url);
            await convert(url);
            await upload(url);
        },
        concurrency: 2
    })
    console.log('Done');
})();
```